# restrict page content to be displayed to user using nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a site a.com when i visit the site and click on the login button the URL automatically changes to a.com/login in the address bar and the page is redirected to the login page how do configure nginx in such a way that when the user clicks on the login button the URL should change but the page must not be served it should show 404 if he clicks from the page is it possible using nginx?

when click on the login button the URL changes and the page is served but when I refresh I get 404, without refreshing when i click on the login button on the home page URL should redirect but the page must not be served